# Client IP in Docker-Desktop kubernetes nginx-ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, docker-desktop

I have a single node K8s cluster using Docker Desktop, which contains an nginx-ingress and is finally routing traffic to a Keycloak server. I want to be able to view the logged-in client's IP in keycloak, but it's just showing me the cluster IP for every user.

[image: Sessions in Keycloak]

According to keycloak docs, this IP is coming from the X-Forwarded-For or Forwarded headers. Having tried numerous header setting configuration in Nginx I thought I'd look at what Nginx-Ingress is actually receiving:

Nginx Debug Logs after attempt to access from external network:

```
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http map started
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script var: "192.168.65.3"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http map: "" "192.168.65.3"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: "Host"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script var: "my.host.co.uk"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: ""
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: ""
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: "X-Request-ID"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script var: "cf3b0012ab9e6cae65a0419dcb92d69b"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: "X-Real-IP"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script var: "192.168.65.3"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-For"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script var: "192.168.65.3"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-Host"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script var: "my.host.co.uk"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-Port"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script var: "443"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-Proto"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script var: "https"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-Scheme"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script var: "https"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: "X-Scheme"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script var: "https"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: ""
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: ""
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http script copy: ""
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http proxy header: "sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120""
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http proxy header: "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http proxy header: "authorization: Bearer xxx"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http proxy header: "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http proxy header: "sec-ch-ua-platform: "Android""
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http proxy header: "accept: */*"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http proxy header: "sec-fetch-site: same-origin"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http proxy header: "sec-fetch-mode: cors"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http proxy header: "sec-fetch-dest: empty"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http proxy header: "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http proxy header: "accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
2024/01/24 20:15:10 [debug] 41#41: *2460 http proxy header:
"GET /auth/admin/realms/master/ui-ext/sessions?first=0&max=11&type=ALL&search= HTTP/1.1
Host: my.host.co.uk
X-Request-ID: cf3b0012ab9e6cae65a0419dcb92d69b
X-Real-IP: 192.168.65.3
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.65.3
X-Forwarded-Host: my.host.co.uk
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-Scheme: https
X-Scheme: https
sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1
authorization: Bearer xxx
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Android"
accept: */*
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

It looks like it isn't receiving any information about the external client. All the IP addresses mentioned are the Cluster IP `198.162.65.3`.
Am I right in thinking the issue is therefore a level above Nginx?

I've seen various similar questions mentioning to set `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` on the ingress service but that hasn't changed anything.

In terms of what could be handling traffic before it gets to nginx I have the following pods running in kube-system (I assume these are managed by docker desktop).

[image]

It would be useful to get an understanding of how traffic enters the cluster and what side effects may be happening to the request before it reaches nginx.

Many thanks!

EDIT:
Setup:

1. On premises docker-desktop kubernetes cluster, running on ARM64 Mac M1.
2. As far as I know I'm not using any load balancer in the back end, I'm not sure if docker-desktop has set something up in the background though. My router is set to forward requests to the NodePort of the nginx-ingress service.
3. My setup has evolved over time so I'm not sure there's any precise documentation I can send you towards, but here's the basic setup:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "nginx-ingress.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "nginx-ingress.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: NodePort
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    nodePort: 30081
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    nodePort: 30444
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    {{- include "nginx-ingress.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

The ingress handles the requests and diverts to the appropriate service:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ include "nginx-ingress.fullname" . }}-https
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.org/ssl-services: "keycloak"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt
    cert-manager.io/issuer-kind: Issuer
    cert-manager.io/issuer-group: cert-manager.io
  labels:
    {{- include "nginx-ingress.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.host }}
    secretName: letsencrypt-tls
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.host }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /auth
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: keycloak
            port:
              number: 8443
```

The nginx-ingress-controller is defined as so:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: {{.Values.namespace}}
  labels:
    {{- include "nginx-ingress.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec: 
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "nginx-ingress.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels:
        {{- include "nginx-ingress.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - name: nginx-ingress
          args: ["/nginx-ingress-controller", "--default-backend-service={{.Values.namespace}}/default-http-backend-2", "--enable-ssl-passthrough"]
          image: "bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller:1.8.0"
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom: 
                fieldRef: 
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom: 
                fieldRef: 
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          livenessProbe: 
            httpGet: 
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 80
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 443
              name: https
              protocol: TCP
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

EDIT:
Further Debugging:
It seems I get this behaviour even when starting a docker-compose file, standing up just a keycloak container. The ip address shown is that of the docker network. I therefore think docker is interfering somehow...

Comment: Can you explain more about your kubernetes deployment like

1. where is your kubernetes node located i.e on cloud or on prem

2. Are you using any load balancer in the backend if so what type of load balancer are you using

3. Can you share the documentation you are following for configuring this setup or steps for replicating this issue

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni thanks for the reply, I have edited the post with more info.

Comment: Hi `Duane Allman` It looks like all your kubernetes configs are good. Can you check whether the network adapter created for docker desktop is of type NAT'd. If it's NAT'd can you try changing it to some other device type.

Comment: Thanks @KranthiveerDontineni, could you tell me how I might find that information? `ifconfig` shows a whole bunch of interfaces but not sure which one docker is using or how to tell if it's NAT'd (I assume it is).

Comment: Hi `Duane Allman` can you try using `docker network inspect` command or in the docker destop console go to the network tab and check what type of adapter it is using. If it is using NAT'd you can follow following [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/macvlan/) and configure a bridge network which might solve this issue.